# Drupal_add_js is not working inside hook submit

Tags: 7, webforms, forms

I have alter and hook submit for webform. I would like to pop a modal if form is successfully submitted. But drupal_add_js seemed to be not working inside the hook submit.

```
function myModule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

    if($form_id == 'webform_client_form_9') {
        $form['#submit'][] = 'myForm_submit';
    }

}

function myForm_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'myModule') . '/misc/custom.js');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do this with [#attached](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#attached).

Like,

```
if (!empty($form_state['values'])) {
  $form['#attached']['css'] = array(
    drupal_get_path('module', 'ajax_example') . '/ajax_example.css',
  );
  $form['#attached']['js'] = array(
    drupal_get_path('module', 'ajax_example') . '/ajax_example.js',
  );
}
```

Comment: But the script will also load on page load. I just need it to load if the form is submitted..

Comment: Yes, I just gave you one snippet. This has to be wrapped in a condition to check whether the form is submitted. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Aneek Mukhopadhyay is on the right track but if you need it only for submit you should add the code inside an IF statement:

```
if( isset($form_state["values"]) ) {
  $form['#attached']['css'] = array(
    drupal_get_path('module', 'ajax_example') . '/ajax_example.css',
  );
  $form['#attached']['js'] = array(
    drupal_get_path('module', 'ajax_example') . '/ajax_example.js',
  );
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

I think so a javascript file is added when a page loads.In this case page loads after hook_submit gets called.Why dont you try to add the js the time a page loads in hook_init and try.

Thanks,
Keep calm and clear the cache.